# Deleting action on Timeline using JS SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-timeline

I have an 'Add To Timeline' button and I can already add posts to the timeline using another function, but now I want to be able to obtain the requestID of an action so that I can delete it from another javascript function I have. I been searching everywhere but can't find a good example so that I can learn how to obtain the ID, I'm still confused on how to do it. This is the code:

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
       function deleteRead(requestId)
       {        
       FB.api(
             requestId,
               'delete',
                function(response) {
                 if (!response || response.error) {
                        alert('error...');
                 } else {
                     alert('Successfully Deleted!');
                     }
                  });
             }</script>
```

Adding the Action ID number of a post directly works and I'm able to delete the post on my timeline. But I have to make it where it automatically obtains the id for each post.

Do I have to use the PHP SDK in order to obtain the requestID? This is the other code I am using:

```
            <div id="fb-root"></div>
             <script type="text/javascript">
              window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

                 FB.init({
                 appId      : 'I-have-my-app-ID-here', // App ID
                 status     : true, // check login status
                 cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                 xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
                 }); 

             };

              // Load the SDK Asynchronously
             (function(d){
                 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; 
                 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
                 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                 d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
                  }(document));   
                 </script>
```

Even better, Is there a way where I can grab the requestID through PHP and pass it into a variable? depending on the post (if it's added to timeline), so that I can replace it with "requestID" to something like:

```
             <?php echo $requestID; ?>
```

This way I can use the php code inside of my javascript where the requestID is and plus incase you want to use that same requestID that is obtained for something else in that same page. Example: if the post is added to Timeline it will show it's request ID number on that post page, incase you want to show the delete button only if its added to timeline, if it's not added, then don't show the delete button using a conditional statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this:

- Store the IDs in a database for each action. This is not ideas as actions can be deleted from Facebook and can make it out of sync with your database.
- Query the user's actions in real-time and use that to show a list of actions to delete. This is preferred.

Sample code:

```
// get activity from Facebook
$actions = $facebook->api('/me/' . $action_id );
// get ID of last action
echo $actions[0]['id'] );
```

You can then grab the ID of the post from above (e.g. `$actions[0]['id']`) and pass it to your JavaScript function or create a PHP function to delete the action. Optionally, you can loop through `$actions` to search if a particular action already exists, matching by URL, e.g.

```
if ( $actions[0]['data']['article']['url'] == $current_url ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Not working for me, I must be doing something else wrong, I'm just getting an error, " Fatal error: Call to a member function api() on a non-object ,"  and its pointing the error to $actions = $facebook->api('/me/' . $response_id );

Comment: Have you initialised the Facebook class? e.g. `$facebook = new Facebook(...);`?

Comment: this is where im confused, because I had a code already that worked where it was using the jssdk, (posting to timeline, like a post & adding timeline worked) but when adding the phpsdk, i get 2 errors, same error before when using phpsdk:  Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at ........header.php:3) in .......facebook.php on line 37

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at .....header.php:3) in ....facebook.php on line 37

Comment: I'm guess something on my wordpress, maybe my cache plugin is not letting me use your code, i tried removing everything i had for the jsdk and used the phpsdk and same error. Once i add this code it fails me: require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '....myid',
  'secret' => '....mysecret',
i guess this is why im not able to do this, i thought there was a way without using the phpsdk

Comment: WordPress makes it a but more complicated. Make sure you are using the correct path to include the Facebook files in your code. And you don't need to call session_start() in your code as WordPress already calls it for you.

Comment: Wow thanks!!! You're a genius!! I finally got it working, the problem was the session_start(), i edited the facebook.php file and removed the session_start() like u said and now it works!!! I appreciate your help!!!